# Use AutoMapper to Map Un-Mapped Members Via a DI Container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper

Given these classes:

```
    public class Source
    {
        public int SalesManager { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        public int SalesManager { get; set; }

        public SelectList SalesManagers { get; set; }
    }

    public class SalesManagersBuilder
    {
        public SalesManagersBuilder(IDataContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        private readonly IDataContext _db;

        public SelectList BuildList()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

And this configuration:

```
 cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(x => x.SalesManagers,o => o.???);
```

How can I populate `SalesManagers` with AutoMapper using the `SalesMangersBuilder` class pulled from a DI container (StructureMap)? Is this possible to just work in AutoMapper?

Comment: Retrieving the data from database should not be inside AutoMapper. It  violates Single Responsibility Principle. AutoMapper should not need to know underlying database and service layer.

Comment: @Win I agree, so assume SalesManagerBuilder is in my "data" layer.

Answer (score 0):

If this isnt what you need 
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays

you could try Custom value resolvers
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers

I has been a while since I played with automapper so to rusty to give a better answer.